# Why one of my Embeded WAR in an EAR deployed on JBoss has a bad context-root?

Tags: deployment, war, ear, jboss6.x

I have two WAR in my EAR, that should be deployed on a JBoss 6.0.0 Application Server with those WEB-INF/jboss-web:

in services-1.1-SNAPSHOT.war:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 5.0//EN" "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_5_0.dtd">
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/wts</security-domain>
    <context-root>ws</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

in web-1.1-SNAPSHOT.war:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 5.0//EN" "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_5_0.dtd">    
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/wts</security-domain>
    <context-root>web</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

And here is my the META-INF/application.xml of my ear:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd">
<application>
  <display-name>ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <ejb>logging-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>logic-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>services-1.1-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>ws</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>web-1.1-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>web</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

I expect to get /web and /ws Context root in Jboss's admin console.
Instead I get /web and /in services-1.1-SNAPSHOT

Any one knows why? And how to fix it?